# Confused about Publish/Subscribe and returning results

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I am using meteor and i am a bit confused about the relationship between publishing/subscribing to documents and querying/returning collections to a client using the handlebars `#each items` helper.

I understand that by publishing and subscribing to certain documents, i get the reactive updating on the client side browser when things change.

I find my self writing very complex (role oriented) publish functions and writing the equivalent to return items to the client. For example,

```
Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId});
    //role and logic left out on purpose
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{emails:1, profile:1}});
});
```

and the subscribe

```
if (Meteor.userId() != null) {
    Meteor.subscribe("directory");
}
```

Template is called show people and the helper 'users'

```
 Template.show_people.users = function () {
     users = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
     return users;
 };
```

My question is, are things supposed to be done this way?. Do we return our list helpers the same query we used for publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a query cursor to the #each Handlebars function. In fact, it's recommended. In this manner, there will be a smart update of the DOM: when a document is added to the Cursor, Handlebars will only create new DOM nodes for that document, and not recreate the DOM nodes for the documents that were already present. This is **not** the case when you provide an array.

So that third piece of code can just be:

```
Template.show_people.users = function () {
     return Meteor.users.find({});
};
```

Note also that a *collection.find()* done client-side will only look in the documents inside your miniMongo storage... you're **not** doing a search through the entire server database, but only through the documents that the server has published to you.

So that complex, role-oriented logic is only necessary inside your Meteor.publish() function.

Comment: Is the fetch() call what you mean by "'not' the case when you provide an array"? Also, can you provide any insight on where subscribe methods should be referenced. In a large project, our team has placed subscribe's in our initial client/app.js file so that they load first?

Comment: yes, _fetch()_ is what I was alluding to, that method returns an array containing the current documents in your Cursor. As for subscriptions, it really depends whether you want to get that data on startup or after some action by the user. If you want it at startup, I'd suggest you insert the code in a Meteor.startup() block, or in a file in client/lib/. Read [this section in the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) to understand the order in which things are loaded in Meteor.

Comment: Thanks for the referencing documentation. I was having issues with my list never rendering on the first hit but returns after a refresh or re-click of a populate button. I will ask a more specific question to get that resolved.